# Method to display groups of items in differing order, based on a previous page selection

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a map page that will display a list of up to 6 service groupings available in any given state.

Each of those states will link to their own page, where those 6 potential service groups list out the items available to download in each of those groups.

Trying to find a way that if a user were to select the 3rd service group in the available choices for any given state, that once that state page opens, it would display the 3rd group of items first on the page, followed then by 1, 2, 4, 5, 6.

This is a WordPress site, I have things set up for the conditional groupings for the main map page, and I'm using a URL hash on those groupings to pass a number over to the state pages based on the user's selection.

That's no problem so far, so if a user selects the 3rd grouping, then I'm pulling the "3" from the URL on the state page using javascript, then passing that to PHP variable.

*Please note - the groupings on the state pages are not in an array, just 6 separate groupings, conditionally displayed if they contain items.*

What I'm stuck on, is an efficient way of using that resulting "3" to be able to display the 3rd grouping first on the state page - so, displaying those groups as 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6

Or, for a state that doesn't have a 2nd or 6th group, if the 4th group gets selected, displaying the groups as 4, 1, 3, 5

I know I can do this with a lot of repeated code bloat by checking the variable, then hard coding those 6 sections multiple times in varying order, but I assume there must be a better way to code that?

TIA

Comment: This is a lot of verbose explanation, but what _exactly_ you are actually doing, is still quite nebulous. Questions like this should come with some code, that shows how exactly it works.

Comment: _“the groupings on the state pages are not in an array”_ - then I’d probably start with that, and rewrite the whole thing, so that it _does_ use an array. Then it should be relatively easy, to pick the proper elements to display on your following pages, by simply picking them via the correct index.